# Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\SomeJob::failed() must be an instance of Exception, null given [Larave Queue]

Tags: php, laravel

I have below piece of code where failed method do what it supposed to do.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Exception;

class SomeJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $SomeVar;

    public function __construct($SomeVar)
    {
        $this->SomeVar = $SomeVar;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        //some code
    }

    public function failed(Exception $e) //Approach 1 
    {
        // some code
    }
    public function failed($e) //Approach 2
    {
        // some code
    }
    public function failed() //Approach 3
    {
        // some code
    }

}
```

But it's show message below on the Log :

> Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\SomeJob::failed() must be an instance of Exception, null given, called in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php on line 174 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\SomeJob::failed() must be an instance of Exception, null given, called in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php on line 174 at app/Jobs/SomeJob.php:27).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is your `failed` method supposed to do? What does the code that calls it look like?

Comment: It's DB column update & `failed`  method doing it correctly.

Comment: In `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php`
    `public function failed(array $data, $e)
    `{
        `$command = unserialize($data['command']);

        `if (method_exists($command, 'failed')) {
            `$command->failed($e);
        `}
    }`

Comment: I'm using Laravel 6.18.29

Comment: Since that function prototype doesn't do anything to dictate what type or value `$e` might have, it seems to me that yours shouldn't either, so your approach 2 should be correct.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yes, indeed. But approach 2 also shows same Log. What can I do in this scenario?

Comment: The exact same error, or a similar error? I can see no reason why you would ever get "must be an instance of Exception, null given" from a function call where the type isn't specified in the prototype. So, maybe you edited a different line or forgot to save / upload the change after editing it, or the second error comes from somewhere else, or something is cached somewhere.

Comment: Yeah! You were right, it was cached somewhere. After restarting the docker container, its start working. @GregSchmidt

Answer (score 0):

you must set "\" before Exception alias

```
public function failed(\Exception $e = null)
{
    //handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately it does not working.